# Playing videos placed out of web-root in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, video, readfile, mediaelement.js, magnific-popup

I have created a script to play videos (mp4) placed outside of webroot in CodeIgniter. I used a different controller to get request and respond video file using readfile. On client side I am using jquery, magnific popup and mediaelement.js to play videos.

The problem is playing different video and closing popup is actually making CI script slow to load. I am posting my controller code:

```
    class Load extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            $url = base_url(uri_string());
            $baseurl = base_url('load/index');      
            $path = str_replace($baseurl,'',$url);      
            $file_name = basename($path);
            $file_path = str_replace($file_name,'',$path);
            $file_name = urldecode($file_name);
            $file_type = '';    
            $real_path = '';

            $this->db->where('file_path', $file_path);
            $this->db->where('file_name', $file_name);
            $query = $this->db->get('media');

            // if user exists
            if($query->num_rows() == 1) 
            {
                $result = $query->result();
                $file_type = $result[0]->file_type;
            } 

            $this->db->where('path', $file_path);       
            $query = $this->db->get('pathalias');

            // if user exists
            if($query->num_rows() == 1) 
            {
                $result = $query->result();
                $real_path = $result[0]->alias;                                 
            } 

            $path = $real_path.'/'.$file_name;

            header('Content-Type: '.$file_type); 
            readfile($path);
        }
    }
```

Comment: there could be a quicker way if you use iframes, load those videos into iframes but obviously you have to upload those videos on YT or any other site.

Comment: Sounds like the typical problem of one request keeping the session open, so other requests from the same client have to wait. Try explicitly closing the session before outputting the video data.

Comment: Can I do something at client side to stop receiving video stream and closing http connection. I am using [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/)